# Enable "Add New" button of RadGrid after selecting items from RadComboBox which is outside of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

In my Web page, I have Telerik RadGrid and outside of RadGrid I have a Telerik RadCombobox.
My requirement is that If user has not selected any Item from the outside RadCombobox and tries to click on "Add New" button of RadGrid (to add new record in it). It should display a msg/alert "Please select Item from RadCombobox".
After selection from RadCombobox, user shall be able to add new records in RadGrid.

Below is the HTML code:

```
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" Height="200" Width="240" AutoPostBack="true"
      DropDownWidth="310" EmptyMessage="- Select Product -" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" CausesValidation="false"
      Filter="StartsWith" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AllowCustomText="true"
      DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Code" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>

    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10"
         OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" ShowFooter="True" GroupingEnabled="False"        
        AllowAutomaticInserts="True" OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_InsertCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">            
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>
        <MasterTableView Width="100%" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" InsertItemDisplay="Top" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnFirstPage">

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ChatTo" HeaderText="To" UniqueName="ChatTo" SortExpression="ChatTo"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ChatCc" HeaderText="Cc" UniqueName="ChatCc" SortExpression="ChatCc"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ChatSubject" HeaderText="Subject" UniqueName="ChatSubject" SortExpression="ChatSubject"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ChatContent" HeaderText="Content" UniqueName="ChatContent" SortExpression="ChatContent"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>                   

                <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteColumn"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>                   
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
            </EditFormSettings>
            <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Add new record" RefreshText="Refresh"></CommandItemSettings>
        </MasterTableView>           
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCompany.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            RadGrid1.AllowAutomaticInserts = true;            
        }
    }
```

I tried using above approach to fulfill the requirement but its not working as expected. 
I am very new in Telerik, Please help me with some solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `RadComboBox`.

```
protected void RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (RadComboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        GridCommandItem cmditem = (GridCommandItem)RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ctrl = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)cmditem.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton");
        ctrl.Enabled = false;

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton btn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)cmditem.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }

    else
    {
        // alert
    }
}
```

Please notice, you have to set `AutoPostBack` property of `RadComboBox` to true, else it won't fire. And add `CommandItemsDisplay="Top"` to you `MasterTableView`:

```
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
```

If you added `CommandItemDisplay="Top"` to your `MasterTableView` you do have those buttons above your RadGrid, don't you?

[image]

Comment: Hi Roman, Thank you for the reply.
But I am using RadComboBox in my web page not RadCheckBox.
Also, this RadComboBox is outside of RadGrid.
Please let me know the solution based on my requirement.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Please wait a second.

Comment: No worries. Waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the help. But when I try to implement your logic at my side, I see that the RadComboBox event is little different from yours:

`code` 
 protected void ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCompany.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            RadGrid1.AllowAddNewRow = true;
        }
    } 
`code`

Also I am getting Red line at "AllowAddNewRow" . Please suggest what shall I change in my code.

Comment: Are you using Telerik.Web.UI?

Comment: yes Im using Telerik.Web.UI
Also, please check my above comment again. I had added one more line in which im facing error.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WebForms, but I think the property to achieve this is `RadGrid1.AllowAutomaticInserts` instead of `AllowAddNewRow`

Comment: I tried using "RadGrid1.AllowAutomaticInserts" but , its not working as per my requirement. 
When I click on "AddNew" button of RadGird without selecting any data from outside RadComboBox, I am able to add the new records which I don't want. Please reply some solution.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the source code of your RadGrid? That may help me finding a solution.

Comment: Please check my edit question. I had pasted necessary code there. Please let me know what mistake I am doing in my code. Thanks

Comment: Please let me know where is this control defined in RadGrid HTML code: 
"Control ctrl = cmditem.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton");" ??

Comment: The namespace of `Control` is `System.Web.UI`. You don't have to declare it in HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is not working as per my requirement. Also, I don't want to hide the visibility of "Add New" button which is there in RadGrid, just I want to disable it if no items are selected from RadComboBox. Please suggest some other solution.

Comment: Please somebody help me to achieve this functionality. Its urgent

Comment: Please be patient. I'm on it but cannot work on it continuously.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Will wait for your reply.

Comment: I made an update of my answer. Please notice, it's not 100% finished. I just wanted you to show where I'm working. `btn.Enabled = false` will disable the text, but not the image. I'm still working on disable the image.

Comment: I understood your point. 
But I have 1 query that is in your code, you are using 
LinkButton "InitInsertButton" and Control "AddNewRecordButton"
and trying to disable Linkbutton.

But I am not using this LinkButton in my RadGrid to add new records, nor I have defined Control "AddNewRecordButton" in my HTML code. Then how it will work with my code ?

I am sorry if my question is senseless as I am using Telerik controls 1st time and I am not aware of many things.

Thanks.

Comment: You say you don't have "AddNewRecordButton". See the HTML code of my answer. Have you added this?

Comment: Yes in my posted question, you may see that I have added the HTML code of line that you told. But I have no Button or LinkButton with id = AddNewRecordButton or id = InitInsertButton in my RadGrid HTML code. Then how this code will work as per my requirement ? Please reply

Comment: Sorry to say but your code is still not working as I have no Button or LinkButton with id = AddNewRecordButton or id = InitInsertButton in my RadGrid HTML code. Please suggest what changes shall I make ?

Comment: If you added the HTML I provided, you should have those buttons above your RadGrid. They aren't in my HTML as well. See my edit and have a look at this Telerik link: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/commanditem/overview

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I made the changes as per your solution in RadGrid "ItemDataBound" event as well as in RadComboBox "SelectedIndexChanged" event and its working fine as per my requirement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void radComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
{
if (radComboBox1.SelectedIndex==0)
{
        //Alert Message       
}
else
{
   radGridView1.AllowAddNewRow = true;
   //or Visible The Button
}
}
```